# Inout arguments are not allowed to alias each other

Tags: ios, swift

Getting error if passing the same variable for both parameters. 
Can anyone explain why we can't pass the same variable in input parameter function whereas we can pass in the normal function

```
func swapTwoInts(a: inout Int, b: inout Int) {

    print(a)
    print(b)

}

var a = 12    

swapTwoInts(a: &a, b: &a)
```

Comment: Firstly, you are trying to swap the same variable's value to itself! why?

Comment: Unrelated: there is already a [swap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1540890-swap) function.

Comment: why is there a memory conflict in single thread swift ? i never heard of memory conflict in javascript

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID545):

> Within a function, don’t access a value that was passed as an in-out
>   argument, even if the original value is available in the current
>   scope. Accessing the original is a simultaneous access of the value,
>   which violates Swift’s memory exclusivity guarantee. For the same
>   reason, you can’t pass the same value to multiple in-out parameters.

In your example, you created 2 copy of same variable. When the function returns, they must be assigned to the original argument. This is the conflict in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

because in your case  inout params requires 2 different variables,

why because you are swapping two variables and returning them directly, 
so passing the same variable twice wont work

because as inout parameters that means after the function ends it return the parameters with their new values,

passing in the same variable is trying to set 2 value for the same variable that wont work sir,

read more about inout parameter and how they execute [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/5/10/inout-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

passing the variable 'a' as the value for both parameters produces a conflict because it tries to perform two write accesses to the same location in memory at the same time.

“**Characteristics of Memory Access**

There are three characteristics of memory access to consider in the context of conflicting access: whether the access is a read or a write, the duration of the access, and the location in memory being accessed. Specifically, a conflict occurs if you have two accesses that meet all of the following conditions:

- At least one is a write access.
- They access the same location in memory.
- Their durations overlap.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.0)”. Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/in/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-0/id881256329